# Draw in a canvas and save it to a larger image

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement, like drawing something in canvas and saving it to a larger image. As of now whatever I draw inside onDraw() method and save, it gives device provided image/canvas size, say something around 538(w)/852(h). I need image of almost double size, around 1000(w)/1500(h) without losing resolution. Any sample code, reference link would help definitely. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create Bitmap of desired size and draw on it using canvas:

```
int w = 1000, h = 1500;
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

Finally you will have you bmp with your drawing and necessary dimentions.

EDIT::

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int w = 1000, h = 1500;
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
    Canvas mycanvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    super.onDraw(mycanvas);

    ...
}
```

Comment: agree, but currently whatever I am doing everything inside onDraw(Canvas c). How to save it to a larger image ? Is it something I need to redraw using your provided code and save it ?

Comment: Understood, in that case you can unlink current canvas from your parent View class and link your Bitmap which you created with necessary size.

Answer (score 0):

First get bitmap of your view using the function `getDrawingCache()`, then scale the bitmap as per your requirements.

```
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
//bitmap = bitmap.createScaledBitmap(..as your requirements..);
```

**EDIT**

You are saying that you want image in higher quality. You can't simply get a higher quality image from a lower quality image. However you can apply bitmap filtering to get slightly better quality.

```
Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(/*width, height, bla bla bla*/);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
Rect srcRect = new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
Rect destRect = new Rect(0,0,output.getWidth(), output.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRect, paint);
```

Comment: scaling bitmap yields resolution lost, right ?  my requirement is to get a "good resolution" even if I see this image zoomed in from any other third party tool, like, gallery, imageviewer etc.